# how to access column values based on other column values in CSV and find average of it

Tags: python, csv

I want to access column 3 values i.e `Total_network's_Disbelief` column based on indexes from index list and have to find out average of that values.  from `OutCSV.csv` [link](https://github.com/Samradnyee/csv/blob/master/OutCSV.csv). 
index contains values [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56]. 
`list1` contains first column `Time` in csv file

```
col=3
values=[]
with open('OutCSV.csv') as csvfile: 
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for x in range(0,highest):
   if list1[x] == 70:
    index.append(x)
   #print(index)
   for x in range(0,len(index)):
    print(index[col])
    values.append(int(index[col]))
csum = sum(values)
cavg = sum(values)/len(values)
print("Sum of column %d: %f" % (col, csum))
print("Avg of column %d: %f" % (col, cavg))
```

Comment: `pandas` could be useful for parsing CSVs and finding averages of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('OutCSV.csv')
index_list = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56]
mask = df.index.isin(index_list)
# find average of 3rd column
mean_col_3 = df[mask].iloc[:, 2].mean()
# find average of 1st column
mean_col_1 = df[mask].iloc[:, 0].mean()
```